# videoview Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Tags: android, android-videoview

When I use `VideoView` it throws an exception. This is my code:

```
mMediaController = new MediaController(this);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://www.somesite.com/household/uploads/jobs.mp4"));
mVideoView.setMediaController(mMediaController);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
```

This is the exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.spark.peak, PID: 12065
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:853)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:337)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:350)
    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1113)
    at android.widget.VideoView$5.onError(VideoView.java:560)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:3823)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7233)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Which Context you use in `new MediaController(this)`?

Comment: applicationContext

Comment: This is exactly the problem. You can see in the log: `token null is not for an application`. You need an `Activity` context.

Answer (score 0):

**EASIEST WAY**

This will fix the issue :

```
 val mediaController = MediaController(this)
```

using the correct context